# Cordova Plugin for logging errors to a text file

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a hybrid app for android, Ios and win10.Is there any plugin available to create an error log file(.txt) to log all the errors?If not how can I log all the errors into a file.In all the above platforms?(I know logtofile plugin works only on android as of now!!)

Answer (score 0):

I had used the instructions in this blog [Writing to a file](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file) a while back to write my logs to a file.